# term for probability of failure for a sequence of events

Tags: probability, terminology

I'm wondering if there's a term or principle related to the following:

If, given a sequence of independent events, even if each iteration has a high probability of succeeding (say 99%), then making the sequence sufficiently large (say 100) will cause the probability of all of the events succeeding improbable.

I was under the impression there was such a term dealing with domino's, but the term "domino effect" seems to infer that there is a 100% chance that one event causes the next event, and I'm not finding any other terms.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  If the events are dependent, as you say, then there need be no failure ever.  Or there might be.  We need to know more about the dependence.  In any case, I don't believe that there is a single term which covers all cases.

Comment: If any part of the sequence fails, then the whole system fails.   So in the above, the probability of the system succeeding would be 0.99^100 = 36%...   (even though each iteration has a probability of success, the overall system is likely to fail)

Comment: No...you told us the events were *dependent*, so you can't use the simple product formula you invoke.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm using the term dependent incorrectly...  I was meaning that any step of the sequence succeeding was dependent on the previous step of the sequence succeeding...   What the terminology for that be then?

Comment: Oh, that's different.  In that case you are, I believe, just saying that we only get to stage $11$, say, if the first $10$ stages were successes but that, conditioned on the first $10$ stages being successful, the $11^{th}$ trial has a $.99$ chance of success.  In that case, yes.  The product formula does apply.  But that's not what *dependent* means.  Again, I don't think there's a term that describes this situation, but it is standard enough.

Comment: Now I'm very curious as to what you infer dependent to mean...

Comment: Really, just saying the stages are *independent* covers what you want.  You can imagine that all stages occur, even with the understanding that the system as a whole fails if and only if at least one stage fails.

Comment: *Dependent* means that knowing the results of one trial alter the probabilities of subsequent trials.  In an extreme case, you could say that all of your events much match the first trial.  Usually, of course, dependence isn't deterministic in this way.

Comment: As to the underlying question... of if for any $p$ with $0<p<1$ and any $\epsilon>0$ if there exists a sufficiently large $n$ such that $p^n<\epsilon$... the answer is obviously yes.  Just use the logarithm base $p$ to find the desired $n$.

Comment: As for a standard phrase to describe this that occurs in common language... "[murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)"

Comment: Ok, thanks.   Updated question to remove the word dependence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the term "The law of truly large numbers" is what you're looking for.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_truly_large_numbers